# Docsethomepage.aspx - File Not Found

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, document-set, file

I migrate a site collection from version 2010 to the 2013.
I have a list with a custom content type. (document set).
When I try to open a document with the url

```
mysite/listName/Forms/myContentType/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=1
```

I get the error

> File Not Found

I checked the log and the error is on this file

```
mysite/_controltemplates/ToolBar.ascx
```

The file `ToolBar.ascx` exists in the hive `/15/ControlTemplates/`

I tried to remove the import of that page from the `docsethomepage.aspx` page of the content type (`_cts/myContentType/docsethomepage.aspx`) but it is still not working.

**UPDATE**

I tread to delete the page `_cts/myContentType/docsethomepage.aspx` but I still get the same error, so I guess I am editing the wrong page.

Comment: Can you see the document inside the library?

Comment: yes, I can open the document library and I can see the property of the item (with the custom content type). But when I try to open an item (click on the document set) I get the error

Comment: You can open up SPD and check if the Page got migrated or not.

Comment: The page is there, but my, but if I change the page `_cts/myContentType/docsethomepage.aspx ` I do not see changes

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this issue in the past. In the end I had to carry out these steps:

1. Delete the `docsethomepage.aspx` file.
2. Copy in a fresh `docsethomepage.aspx` file.
3. Check out the `docsethomepage.aspx` file, then check it back in.
4. Go into the document set's settings and check *Update the Welcome Page of Document Sets inheriting from this content type*

[This](http://www.dotnetquest.com/post/2013/02/20/Replace-DocSetHomePageaspx-of-existing-document-set-content-type) was where I found my answer.