# Document Set "Name" Link is taking me to the wrong location

Tags: content-type, document-set

I created a Document Library that uses Content Types Document, Folders, and Document Set. Clicking on a Document set should bring the user to a document set welcome page which shows them the contents as well as some custom stuff I've written to stick in a Content Editor web part. The path to the documentsetwelcomepage.aspx is...

/Path/To/Site/LibraryName/Forms/Document%20Set/docsethomepage.aspx

I believe this is by default..?
However when I click the "Name (linked to document with edit menu)" link in the Document Library AllItems view it takes me to to this location...

/Path/To/Site/LibraryName/Forms/Folder/docsethomepage.aspx

Which of course 404's. My question is first, how do I change the target of the "Name (linked to document with edit menu)" link. My other question is.. In other implementations of Document Sets I seem to remember there being url parameters like ID, List GUID, RootFolder.. etc. Have I done something to royally jack up my Document Sets if the Name link is taking me to the above link with no parameters?

Comment: Correction.. The URL Parameters do show up fine if I copy the docsethomepage.aspx to /folder/ directory. Now I would just really rather have it link to the /Document Set/ directory.

Comment: Check this, might be the same problem: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140633/docsethomepage-aspx-file-not-found

Comment: Hmm.. I'm trying to follow that answer but I'm not sure where "Update the Welcome Page of Document Sets inheriting from this content type" is... Another piece of info I noticed is that 4 of the 5 are experiencing this issue and it is the 4 that were created from templates of the 1st one. A last resort fix would be delete the 4 and make them all from scratch but they are all exact copies of one another with different names....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something about making these document library out of templates caused SharePoint to think the Document Sets were folders. My solution was to get an intern to painstakingly recreate all the Doc Sets from scratch. Worked for me.